# The Quaternion Group and other Group Theory Counterexamples

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

The quaternion group $Q_8$ is a common counterexample to many statements. For example, even though every subgroup is normal, it is not abelian, a direct product, or even a semidirect product! In addition, $Q_8/Z(Q_8) \cong C_2 \times C_2$ but every subgroup of order 4 is cyclic.

What other "conjectures" does the quaternion group **disprove**, and are there other groups which are common counterexamples?

Comment: http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Quaternion_group

Comment: *even though every subgroup is normal, it is not abelian, a direct product, or even a semidirect product!* - The shock! The horror! :D

Answer (score 4):

The quaternion group $Q_{8}$ is also used to show that two non-isomorphic groups may have the same character table. The character table of $Q_{8}$ is the same as the character table of $D_{8}$, the dihedral group of order 8.

Answer (score 4):

The (generalized) quaternion groups are the only non-cyclic finite $p$-groups with a unique subgroup of order $p$.